# Entity Framework Caching

Tags: entity-framework, caching

I'am reading a article about the differences between Nhibernate and EF.
But i could not understand what they wanted to say with caching on a field.

> As for Entity Framework, the ObjectContext/DbContext holds the configuration, model and acts as the Unit of Work, holding references to all of the known entity instances. This class is therefore not lightweight as its NHibernate counterpart and it is not uncommon to see examples where an instance is cached on a field.

I did not create a link to article, because i was not 100% sure it was allowed.

Comment: Yes, you can provide a link to the article.

Comment: [Is this the article?](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2012/06/07/differences-between-nhibernate-and-entity-framework.aspx)

Comment: [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2012/06/07/differences-between-nhibernate-and-entity-framework.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Note the wording carefully; they are speaking of the `DbContext` itself, and comment that it is not uncommon to see examples where "the instance" (the DbContext) is cached on a field.

What they mean is, rather than creating and destroying a `DbContext` object with a local scope in a method, you'll see people save the `DbContext` instance to a field of a broader object and reuse it.

Comment: Is it not normal to share you context between different repositories in case of repository pattern?
As also stated on MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx); the cost of opening and closing database connection is very high.

Comment: @JVGAG `Repository != DbContext != Connection`. ADO.NET (which runs behind Entity Framework) handles all your connection pooling for you. Whether your DbContext is long-lived or not has *absolutely nothing* to do with that. The page you link to explains that ADO.NET/EF handles all that for you - only opening/closing the connections "as needed"

Comment: Are they using this approach in following link ? [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)
They are holding one Dbcontext for multiple repositories.

Comment: @JVGAG They are 'holding' one DbContext across multiple repositories, yes. But that has nothing to do with the underlying DbConnections, btw.